When I run Python code using virtual environment from terminal, it fails vs. running from within IDE
From within Visual Studio Code [1.91.1] on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, running Debian 12, the code runs successfully when I start with Main.py using "Run and Debug". I have installed all of the necessary packages within the virtual environment. However, when I try to run from terminal:

sudo python3 /home/pi/CodeAsynchronous/Main.py

The execution fails, ending with the error message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'.
The project uses a virtual environment and seems to not be loading the packages correctly when I run from terminal, possibly not loading the correct interpreter?

Why are you using sudo?

I've always run it that way in the past. If I remove sudo it yields the same results.

"If I remove sudo it yields the same results." - Oh, so your virtualenv just isn't active. sudo would ignore it anyway though.

Does this answer your question? sudo privileges within python virtualenv

It's also worth mentioning that you shouldn't run commands as root unless you have a good reason, which could be something like, you need to interact directly with a hardware device.

You are correct -- Activating the vritual environment in terminal combined with removing sudo works -- thx !

Probably because the IDE automatically activates the virtual environment for you.
Try running: source <venv>/bin/activate on Linux or <venv>\Scripts\activate.bat on windows
Full documentation here:

A virtual environment may be “activated” using a script in its binary directory (bin on POSIX; Scripts on Windows). This will prepend that directory to your PATH, so that running python will invoke the environment’s Python interpreter and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full path. The invocation of the activation script is platform-specific (<venv> must be replaced by the path to the directory containing the virtual environment):


Activating the virtual environment from the terminal works ! I also did need to eliminate "sudo" from the command, as this seems to overide the virtual environment in favor of the global.
